# How to keep quote inside quote marks?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've this quote that should occupy the full length of site on PC and Tablets, and a line when in smartphones.

Right now it renders like this:

[image]

**CODEPEN:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/BaoOmXw

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10%">
    <p><span style="font-size: 6.6em; color: yellowgreen">&#8220;</span>QUE CADA UNO DÉ COMO PROPUSO EN SU CORAZÓN, NO DE MALA GANA NI POR OBLIGACIÓN, PORQUE DIOS AMA AL DADOR ALEGRE<span style="font-size: 6.6em; color: yellowgreen;">&#8221;</span></p>.
    <p>2 CORINTIOS 9:7</p>
</div>
```

the lines are:

1) QUE CADA UNO DÉ COMO PROPUSO EN SU CORAZÓN,
2) NO DE MALA GANA NI POR OBLIGACIÓN,
3) PORQUE DIOS AMA AL DADOR ALEGRE.  2 CORINTIOS 9:7

**Expected result:**

[image]

Where instead of "Steve Jobs", we have: 2 CORINTIOS 9:7.

**UPDATE 1:**

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

It's taking form thanks for the answer of Zohir. Just the ending quotes shoud be next to the last word of the quote. The html is like that but it's not rendering accordingly. And the "Corintios... " part should be outside.

[image]

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/QWjmorP

I've change the CSS so it doesn't affect the rest of the document:

```
/* QUOTE */

.quote_container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.p_quote {
  padding: 10px;
}

.i_quote {
  color: yellowgreen;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.top_quote {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.bottom_quote {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh I'm still new to this but I attempted this using a table instead:

```
<div class="container">
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5px" width="100%">
    <tr align="left" valign="top">
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><span style="font-size: 6.6em; color: yellowgreen;">&#8220;</span></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><span>QUE CADA UNO DÉ COMO PROPUSO EN SU CORAZÓN, NO DE MALA GANA NI POR OBLIGACIÓN, PORQUE DIOS AMA AL DADOR ALEGRE</span></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: bottom;"><span style="font-size: 6.6em; color: yellowgreen;">&#8221;</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">2 CORINTIOS 9:7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

If you the text to break at specific points you'll have to explicitly tell it to, either by using `<br>` or put each line of text in a separate element *(the approach i went with)*

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[container] {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}

i {
  color: yellowgreen;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<div container>
  <i class="fas fa-quote-left top"></i>
  <div>
    <p>QUE CADA UNO DÉ COMO PROPUSO EN SU CORAZÓN,</p>
    <p>NO DE MALA GANA NI POR OBLIGACIÓN,</p>
    <p>PORQUE DIOS AMA AL DADOR ALEGRE. 2 CORINTIOS 9:7</p>
  </div>
  <i class="fas fa-quote-right bottom"></i>
</div>
```

I highly recommend using fonts for the quote symbols, the normal chars `“` and `”` are difficult to control because as you can see they have an excess height.

Comment: May you tell me how [container] works? It will affect any div with class container? Also the "*" will affect everythinh? Would you mind changing it with specfici classes in the tags. Right now it doesn't render approperly on my machine. Please, see update 2.

Comment: @Omar I suggested you look up css selectors to understand what is doing what. All the selectors i used are subject to change to your liking they're only meant to show you how to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this again

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10%">
    <p><span style="font-size: 6.6em; color: yellowgreen">&#8220;</span>QUE CADA UNO DÉ COMO PROPUSO EN SU CORAZÓN, NO DE MALA GANA NI POR OBLIGACIÓN, PORQUE DIOS AMA AL DADOR ALEGRE<br><span style="font-size: 6.6em; color: yellowgreen;">&#8221;</span></p>.
  <br>
</div>
    <p>2 CORINTIOS 9:7</p>
```

Comment: Oh, you want something different. Alright, I updated my code. Try that.